# How do I know if my answer satisfies Rolle's theorem?

Tags: calculus

Given a function on $[0,2]$,

$$f(x) = x^3 - x ^2 -2x +2$$

I know the answer has to be between $[0,2]$, but for some reason, my answer isn't being accepted. I derived the function and got the following:
$$f'(x) = 3x^2 - 2x -2 \ .$$
I then set it equal to zero and found $x$ using the quadratic formula. This is what I got for $x$.

$$x = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{28}}{6}$$

Comment: What do you need to find actually? By the way, your last equation is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know the solution of a quadratic equation

> $$ax^2+bx+c=0\implies x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$

The solution is

$$ \frac{1}{3}+\frac{\sqrt {7}}{3},\, \frac{1}{3}-\frac{\sqrt {7}}{3}. $$

Now, you need to choose the right answer from the above

Comment: I originally put my answers out like that, but I still got it wrong. Then I realized that the answer would be in the [0,2] interval, so that rules out the latter answer.

Comment: @igknighton: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Rolle's theorem applies whenever $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are equal.

Here $a=0$ and $b=2$. Plugging in 0 yields $f(0)$ =2. Plugging in $2$ yields $f(2) = 2$, So Rolle's Theorem applies.

$x=\dfrac{2 \pm \sqrt{28}}{6} =\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{\sqrt7}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{\sqrt7}{3}$

You just need to pick the answer that lies in the interval [0,2] now. (Note that one of these is negative and the other is not.)